# Get calendar's month in onCalendarPageChangeListener Android

Tags: java, android-studio, calendarview

I'm creating a small application that uses the material-calendar-view library from applandeo.

I'm trying to get the current month and year whenever the user clicks the forward or previous buttons.

```
    public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

             CalendarView calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

            //Move to another Activity
            calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(eventDay -> {
                   // code to move to another activity
                   //...
            });

            calendarView.setOnForwardPageChangeListener(new OnCalendarPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange() {
                    showToast();
                }
            });


            calendarView.setOnPreviousPageChangeListener(new OnCalendarPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange() {
                  showToast();
                }
            });
    }

    private void showToast(){
        // set month and year here....
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"current month " + month + " current year " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Is there a way of getting the currently shown month and year?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

## App Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

## Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Fragment:

```
public class CustomCalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<EmployeeLeave> mLeaves = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventDay> mEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private EmployeeViewModel mViewModel;
    private CalendarView mCalendarView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_calendar_view, container, false);

        CalendarView mCalendarView = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setHeaderColor(R.color.colorSubraTamarillo);
        mCalendarView.setHeaderLabelColor(R.color.colorWhite);
        mCalendarView.setForwardButtonImage(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right));
        mCalendarView.setPreviousButtonImage(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left));

        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        getLeaveListByDate(getFirstDate(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar), getLastDate(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar));

        //-----------------------------------------------| Previous Month
        mCalendarView.setOnPreviousPageChangeListener(new OnCalendarPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.MONTH, mCalendar.get( mCalendar.MONTH ) - 1);
                getLeaveListByDate(getFirstDate(mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar), getLastDate(mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar));
            }
        });
        //-----------------------------------------------| Forward Month
        mCalendarView.setOnForwardPageChangeListener(new OnCalendarPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.MONTH, mCalendar.get( mCalendar.MONTH ) + 1);
                getLeaveListByDate(getFirstDate(mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar), getLastDate(mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mCalendar));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    //=================================================| Get start date and end date from current month
    private String getFirstDate(int dayOfMonth, Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(dayOfMonth, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); //(Month, 1)
        return getInstance().getFormatFromStringDate("yyyy-MM-dd", cal.getTime());
    }

    private String getLastDate(int dayOfMonth, Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(dayOfMonth,  cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); //(Month, 31)
        return getInstance().getFormatFromStringDate("yyyy-MM-dd", cal.getTime());
    }

    public String getFormatFromStringDate(String pattern, Date date) {
        return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date); //java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(ts.getTime())
    }

    //=================================================| Creates event from employee list
    private void getLeaveListByDate(String fromDate, String toDate) {
        String json = "[{\"empList\":[{\"department\":\"Sewing\",\"designation\":\"Sr. Manager\",\"eid\":\"1004\",\"FirstName\":\"Mohammad Shahabul Alam\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-02T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"},{\"department\":\"Sewing \",\"designation\":\"Helper\",\"eid\":\"0011\",\"FirstName\":\"al harbi Accounting Manager\",\"Gender\":\"Female\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-02T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"}],\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-02T00:00:00\",\"totalEmployee\":2},{\"empList\":[{\"department\":\"Sewing\",\"designation\":\"Jr. Operator\",\"eid\":\"00021\",\"FirstName\":\"tanver\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"LastName\":\"rana\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-03T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"}],\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-03T00:00:00\",\"totalEmployee\":1},{\"empList\":[{\"department\":\"Sewing\",\"designation\":\"Sr. Manager\",\"eid\":\"1004\",\"FirstName\":\"Mohammad Shahabul Alam\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-04T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"}],\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-04T00:00:00\",\"totalEmployee\":1},{\"empList\":[{\"department\":\"Sewing \",\"designation\":\"Helper\",\"eid\":\"0011\",\"FirstName\":\"al harbi Accounting Manager\",\"Gender\":\"Female\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-05T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"CL\"},{\"department\":\"Admin\",\"designation\":\"Asst. Manager\",\"eid\":\"00100\",\"FirstName\":\"shek jamal\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-05T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"}],\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-05T00:00:00\",\"totalEmployee\":2},{\"empList\":[{\"department\":\"Sewing \",\"designation\":\"Helper\",\"eid\":\"0011\",\"FirstName\":\"al harbi Accounting Manager\",\"Gender\":\"Female\",\"LastName\":\"\",\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-07T00:00:00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"status\":\"SL\"}],\"leaveDate\":\"2020-03-07T00:00:00\",\"totalEmployee\":1}]";

        ArrayList<EmployeeLeave> arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<EmployeeLeave>>(){}.getType());
        mLeaves.addAll(arrayList);
        for (EmployeeLeave leave : arrayList) {
            Calendar cal = getDayFromString(Calendar.getInstance(), leave.getLeaveDate());
            //mEvents.add(new EventDay(cal, CalendarUtils.getDrawableText(getActivity(), "" + leave.getTotalEmployee(), null, R.color.colorSubraTamarillo, 12)));
            mEvents.add(new EventDay(cal, getCircleDrawableWithText(getActivity(), "" + leave.getTotalEmployee())));
        }
        if (mEvents != null) {
            mCalendarView.setEvents(mEvents);
        }
    }

    //=================================================| Create circle with text drawable
    private Drawable getCircleDrawableWithText(Context context, String string) {
        Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.sample_circle);
        Drawable text = CalendarUtils.getDrawableText(context, string, null, android.R.color.white, 12);
        Drawable[] layers = {background, text};
        return new LayerDrawable(layers);
    }

}
```